# How to access a referenced assembly's types?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

If I reference an assembly A.dll in my project and A.dll references B.dll. My project cannot access the exported namespaces/classes of B.dll, only A.dll. Is there something I can do so I don't have to directly reference B.dll in my project in order to access its classes?

Comment: Please do not repeat tags in question titles.

Comment: @OndrejTucny Oh ok? Didn't realize that was a rule, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way *) You have to reference all assemblies you want to use types for. This implies that if you use A and if you use anything from A that exposes a type from B, you **must** reference the B too.

quick edit: uh, ok, actually there is some way - if you don't want to use B.dll but if you wouldn't mind using a XYZ.dll instead, you could make a XYZ.dll that mimics relevant types from the B.dll, and then try to develop some ticks ased on i.e. assembly redirection.. with it you theoretically could have your app reference A.dll and XYZ.dll but in runtime it would use A.dll and B.dll. If speaking about project&compilation, there are some tricks the compiler uses (or used to use) to support cross-platform compilation (i.e. stubbing assemblies from WindowsPhone just to get references satisfied)..

*) afterthought: you could try using `dynamic` and its dynamic binding:

```
// in A.dll
public dynamic Method() {
    return new ClassFromB(); // thing from B.dll
}

// in your app:
// do not ever explicitely name ANY type from:
dynamic foo = ClassFromA.Method();
dynamic result = foo.CallSomething(1,2,3); // even when getting results
dynamic other = result.Boom(foo); // and even when passing params
```

as long as all reference types and methods are be shadowed by `dynamic`, there is some chance it won't ask you to reference the B.dll, since there's no explicit type reference.. - but I actually never tried it for this effect, so I can't tell for 100% sure

however, when using `dynamic` all the time, you will resign from many compile-time checks and any error in parameter types or method names will be rised at runtime only - just like using reflection

Comment: Yeah, I just ended up "mirroring" some enums in A.dll that were present in B.dll. I don't need B.dll (or want to maintain another nuget package for it) because I'm just using some enumerations from it that happen to be used as function arguments in functions a part of A.dll.

Comment: This is purely creating a mess, you should re-architect your projects or just reference `B.dll`.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester It's just silly that I need to reference an entire dll just to use an enum. It's also silly that, in the case that you want to make a  common library that sits on top of things like EF and other libraries, you need to reference those libraries in addition to the common library. Maybe it's not silly and I'm missing something here, but right now it seems like a pointless hurdle. For example, I now have two library references that may potentially be different versions instead of just referencing the same dll (like when using nuget packages)

Comment: @slight you _are_ missing something. Your common library package should include the correct versions of the ones it encapsulates. For big projects, I feel like nuget becomes more of a burden than a tool. That's why we don't use it at our company and use an internal sort of "package" (not nuget) that contains all external binaries. Another technique we frequently use is to just map from external domains to something in our own assemblies (for example, the enum you are talking about). Have a look at automapper, you have to write almost no code to do that.

Comment: @sligh by the way every time we add a reference to a DLL we make sure that "specificversion" is "false".

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Interesting, I'll take a look at automapper, thanks. My common library does include the correct versions, I'm saying the projects that reference the common lib could potentially be the ones using the wrong version. What am I missing though? What is preventing VS from just automatically looking up dependencies down the chain instead of it all being direct references?

Comment: @Slight: not VS. The compiler. Every project (DLL) is compiled separately. When you compile project "foo" -> "foo.dll", the refereces specified in project "foo" are relevant. Depending on exact meaning and setup, "foo" may use some classes/namespaces **different** than "bar" referenced by "foo". I.e. "foo" may use "smart collections 3.4" while "bar" may use the same lib in ver 1.92. Class names and namespaces will be similar, but code different. As long as bar exposes those things only through common IEnumerable/IDictionary/etc it's OK and no reference to "smart collections 1.92" is needed.

Comment: But when Bar exposes them as concrete types, you **have to** add reference from Foo to smartcollections 1.92 (aside from its own 3.4 reference) because the compiler must know that one "BlarghCollection" uses code A (as required by SC3.4) and the other "BlarghCollection" uses code B (as required by SC1.92). That's all generally speaking, but I hope you get the picture. Class name and namespace is not everything. Also, sometimes compiler cannot "just pull that path from that asembly that already uses it" .... because you share assemblies with other people and paths ... differ or change\.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design. Except stuff like using reflection to access any entities in your `B.dll` on run-time, there's no other way than referencing `B.dll` directly.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted you both but the other guy had an alternative in his answer so I gave it him the check since you both posted within seconds of eachother.